# What should I do if it's been 2 weeks and my Schengen visa has not been approved

Tags: schengen-visas, netherlands, application-status, vfs-global

I applied for a Netherlands visa at the VFS center in San Francisco and the status says it was forwarded to the Netherlands Embassy for further processing 15 days ago. I am worried whether VFS has misplaced my passport as I have my US visa in my passport. What should I do?

Comment: Welcome to Travel.SE! 15 calendar days ago or 15 working days?

Comment: Thank you mkennnedy ,15 Calendar Days ago ,ie:7th Feb 2019 .Moreover I have my travel date on 28th Feb 2019 .I don't mind on delay as it's embassy problem ,I am afraid of loss of passport .Also can I check with consulate on status ?

Answer (score 1):

The [FAQ](https://www.vfsglobal.com/Netherlands/USA/visa-services/faqs.html) on the VFS Global web site for Netherlands (the page is headed Netherlands but refers to Dutch Caribbean. I doubt there is much difference)
suggests that processing takes at least 15 business days and may take longer. You should wait another week before contacting them. A link to contact details is given on the same page.

Comment: Yes it's already 15 calendar days and since it's with embassy vfs said they can't do anything .I am not worried about delay I a am worried to ensure my passport is safe and not misplaced ,as in SF embassy hardly there is any crowd for NL visa

Comment: 15 calendar days is not the same as 15 business days. 15 calendar days is about two weeks. 15 business days is about three weeks. You should wait another week.